# MySQL database connection is ok, but queries won't execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="b6_17093244";
$password="password1";
$dbName="b6_17093244_math";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
if($conn)
  echo "ok<br>";
else echo "not ok<br>";
  $sql = "select username from user";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result)
  echo "ok result<br>";
else 
  echo "no result<br>";
?>
```

The output is:

> ok
>   no result

Here is what I have in my database

[image]

Comment: Print out sql error messages in the not ok branches, so you will know what causes the errors and you canfix them afterwards. Link vontains sample code for connection and query error: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Shadow it says "No such file or directory"

Comment: `user` is a reserved word in a bunch of SQL dialects, and thus a bad name for a table or column.

Comment: thanks. i'll change it

Comment: issue resolved or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, `user` is a reserved word - but you should be able to encapsulate `user` with backticks:

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="b6_17093244";
    $password="password1";
    $dbName="b6_17093244_math";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

    echo ( $conn ? 'ok' : 'not ok' ) . '<br />';

    $sql = "select `username` from `user`;";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    echo ( $result ? 'ok result' : 'no result' ) . '<br />';
?>
```

The below works fine for me - the table is called `users` in my case rather than `user`.

```
<?php

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'experiments';

    $conn   =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
    echo ( $conn ? 'db connection ok' : 'db connection failed' ).'<br />';

    $sql='select `username` from `users`';

    $res=$conn->query( $sql );

    echo ( $res ? 'ok result' : 'no result' ) . '<br />';

    while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) echo $rs->username.'<br />';

    $conn->close();

?>
/*
    output
    ------    
    db connection ok
    ok result
    tommy
    joey
    freddy    
*/
```

Comment: The same thing happens

Comment: tried your code. result is "db connection ok, no result". I am using free hosting from byet.host, could it be that there is no problem in my code, but there's a problem with their system?

Comment: Are you 100% certain the details for username,password, host and db are correct?

Comment: not sure with host, but im sure with the rest. i'm using free hosting from byet.host, and in their examples, they used "localhost" as host name so i followed that

Comment: used the wrong host name. it's supposed to be a7h1.byethost6.com, not localhost. thank you for your help!!

Comment: (You have a `;` in your query string in the first example - don't know about MySQL but this will bug out with Oracle. I believe it is better left out in general.)

Comment: @Mat - it's fine to use a semi-colon in mysql

Comment: Ok, but why use it in one place and not the other?

Comment: I didn't even realise I had - makes no difference to the statement though in this case. If it was using a multi statement then it is essential but not here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and post the results

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="b6_17093244";
$password="password1";
$dbName="b6_17093244_math";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
if($conn->connect_errno)
  echo "connect error". $conn->connect_error;
else 
   echo "not ok<br>";
$sql = "select `username` from `user`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$conn->error();
echo "numof rows".$result->num_rows
if($result->num_rows>0)
  echo "ok result<br>";
else 
  echo "no result<br>";
?>
```

Comment: This results to a "Server Error 500"

Comment: do you have mysql running in your system if you have change localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: mysql is not in my system. I'm using free web hosting from byet.host. The page can be viewed here http://a7h1.byethost6.com/sample.php

Comment: there is a problem with server in byehost i think check wiht them

Comment: resolved the problem. used the wrong host name. it's supposed to be  a7h1.byethost6.com, not localhost. thank you

Answer (score 1):

seem you don't fetch the object selected

```
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "ok result<br>";
    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
       echo $obj->username . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: even though i didn't fetch the object, it should have printed "ok result", but it didnt even go inside the if statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99007/discussion-between-jeanl-and-scaisedge).

Comment: resolved the problem. used the wrong host name. it's supposed to be  a7h1.byethost6.com, not localhost. thank you!

Comment: @scaisEdge no it's not

Answer (score 1):

Because you're mixing two different uses of MySQLi

First you're connecting to database using class based object. And querying using just calling a function. Instead do this:

```
# Here changed new mysqli
# to mysqli_connect
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
```

Comment: Tried this. The db connection is unsuccessful. Output is: not ok, no result

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my hostname. It's supposed to be this: a7h1.byethost6.com, not localhost. The examples shown in the hosting site was "localhost", which I followed but turned out to be wrong.

Thank you to everyone who've helped!